# Communicating with the COM PORT in C++

Tags: c++, port

I have to write a program sending messages to the UART converter connected on the COM PORT in C++. I'm actually stuck from the very beggining. I haven't ever dome anything like that and I didn't manage to find any examples.
Could anyone help me out?
Appreciate any help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Boost has a nice library and examples for it: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html

An example for the usage of the boost library was posted here: [Clear input data from serial port in boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706262/clear-input-data-from-serial-port-in-boostasio)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;

int main()
{
    io_service io_service;
    serial_port port(io_service, "/dev/ttyACM0");
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
    vector<char> buf(1);
    read(port, buffer(buf));
    cout << (int) buf[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

same can be done with write:

```
std::string s;
write(port,buffer(s.c_str(),s.size()));
```